# Can I drag a window onto another workspace?

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces

I just updated to 11.04, now if I drag a window to the side of the workspace, the window is maximized to half of the screen. is there a way to move it to another workspace with the mouse?

I know you can right-click on the title and choose "move to Another Workspace", but I would like something quicker.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simple way: Use workspace switcher and drag the window to your desired workspace.

---

Ideal way: install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) (click [HERE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) to install) and enable edge flipping.

After installing, invoke compizconfig-settings-manager with `ccsm` or by searching in Dash. Select Desktop Wall and in the Edge Flipping tab check "Edge Flip Move."
[image: The edge flipping tab of the Desktop Wall plugin lets you set three different types of edge flipping]

Now you can drag windows between workspaces. (Note your pointer needs to press against the side of the workspace around the middle.) It takes a second before the viewport changes.

---

Compizconfig-settings-manager can also set keyboard shortcuts to move windows between workspaces:
[image: You can see my keyboard shortcuts for moving windows between workspaces -- note that I've remapped the dash to Super+space]

Comment: You may also want to disable the GRID plugin if you wish to move windows between workspaces via the edge flipping, the 2 settings both being on can be a little confusing. Personally theres a wrap around setting i also enable,   With Edge flipping  you will also notice that the layout of the  workspaces  is a 2x2 grid, the way unity works I do not think its possible to set a 1x4 grid, so you will need to drag the window up/down to get to 2 of the workspaces.

Comment: Yeah, Grid is what's making Andrea Z's windows fill the half of the screen. I really like Grid's keyboard shortcuts, so I could never get rid of it. But it looks like you can go to the Edges tab and change all of the Resize Actions to None if you wanted to disable that feature. If you like the feature, you can play with Grid's Thresholds to make the timing work to your liking.

Comment: when readint hte first sentence I didn't like the solution as it's only simple as in "it works without adjusting anything additionally" but it's very ugly and requires a bunch of steps and just doesn't work smotthly and fast. But thanks for the other solution! :)

Answer (score 47):

You have a few options:

### Use keyboard shortcuts

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right/Up/Down</kbd> to move the current window as you change workspaces.

### Use the Workspace Switcher

Open the Workspace Switcher (Click the "Workspace Switcher" icon in the launcher or press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then drag-and-drop windows between workspaces.

### Disable edge resize actions

Install the CompizConfig Settings Manager, set the options in **Grid ▸ Edges ▸ Resize Actions** to **None**, and check **Desktop Wall ▸ Edge Flipping ▸ Edge Flip Move**.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the edge resize but only when a specific key is hold?

Comment: @Mood Neither the Grid nor Desktop Wall plugin currently offers this behavior.

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: this answer is the right one. you don't need compiz-manager or similar software.

Comment: this answer is the right one. you don't need compiz-manager or similar software.

Answer (score 2):

The older way of dragging a window outside the screen was sending it partly to another workspace because the "window snapping" feature was absent (the one that you experienced: "if I drag a window to the side of the workspace, the window is maximized to half of the screen"). Now, it is enabled by default. Do disable it, install [Unity Tweaks Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/): Window snapping: OFF.

### [image]

But there is another more elegant way which keeps the window snapping enabled by using  Unity Tweaks Tool.

This may vary, but imagine that we have two horizontal workspaces and the lower hotcorners set for showing workspaces and spreading windows:

[image]

So, we can just go with the pointer to lower right corner to expose all windows and select the one we want to move

[image]

And when that is selected, we put the mouse to the lower left corner to see all workspaces and drag the window where we want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `gnome-panel`.
First type gnome-panel on terminal. Then you will see the list of open programs on bottom left panel(just like taskbar of window). And on bottom right there will be four workspace. Just you need to drag the bottom left program to the workspace of your choice. 
Unlike unity-2d-shell, the program will only be visible if you go to the workspace containing that program.