# How do I move applications from one workspace to another

Tags: 11.10, compiz, workspaces

I'm using 11.10 - please can someone let me know how can I move programs from one workspace to another.

I'm used to the Gnome-2 style - is there a way to achieve something similar in 11.10?

Comment: You can still move programs from workspace to workspace (I do it constantly), maybe you are experiencing some kind of problem.

Comment: You are wrong! Just press Ctrl+Alt and then use an arrow key to switch to another workplace.

Comment: i want to move programs from space to space ... i know how to move from space to space

Comment: you can move windows from Ws to Ws while in the workspace switcher (expo), just pick them up with your cursor & drag to another Ws.

Comment: how is this question not constructive? and why so many downvotes?

Comment: This question should be re-opened. I was wondering this exact same thing, the docs didn't answer it and the answer was here.

Comment: All this question closing starts to bug me. Almost half the topics I find when searching via Google are closed. This really sucks. Here is a clear question and a clear working answer that helped me - wtf is your problem?

Comment: This was a most constructive question, and @jrg's answer helped me to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 69):

You can do it.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> to move programs from one workspace to another.

I also made a fancy-smancy video showing you how its [possible to drag windows between workspaces.](http://youtu.be/dXM4hwfE_W0)

Comment: Works nice. Here are some more options: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39849/can-i-drag-a-window-onto-another-workspace?rq=1

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 :-) (moving between workspaces is the same just without the `Shift` :-)