# Can't drag windows to another workspace on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, compiz, 16.04, workspace-switcher

This used to work on Ubuntu 14.04. I know that I have to enable in CCSM Desktop Wall > Edge Flipping > Edge Flip Move. Also turn off Move Window > Lazy Positioning option.

I disabled Grid as well  in CCSM and Windos snapping in Unity Tweak Tool.

This used to do the trick but it's still not working on 16.04.

I'm using Unity btw.

Anyone else with the same issue or solution?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, you  can. I have `16.04` and by drag to any worksapce. but I use gome-falshback

Comment: I have the same problem, cannot drag window to another workspace, worked great in other versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.

I can solve it from the **CompizConfig Settings Manager** and check the **Edge Flip Pointer** from the **Desktop Wall** settings, but now it will flip to next workspace just when you move the mouse. 
[image]

The **Edge Flip Move** is a confirmed bug on Ubuntu 16.04 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1577328?comments=all

Comment: Thanks! I see that this is working because the mouse cursor triggers the action. It's not the same as before (because I don't want the cursor to move if it's not grabbing a window), but it's close enough.

Comment: I seem to forget that command line name of the program is *ccsm*.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting Compiz to its Default Settings : `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

[How to Enable and Tweak Ubuntu’s Flashy Graphical Effects](http://www.howtogeek.com/167674/how-to-enable-and-tweak-ubuntus-flashy-graphical-effects/)

By default **move on another work-space** `Alt + Ctrl + Shift` +  keys `->` and `<-` **Left / right arrow**

Also : [Can I drag a window onto another workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39849/can-i-drag-a-window-onto-another-workspace)

Also : Drag by mouse to another workspace

[image: Drag by mouse]

---

## for Unity

Click on the **Appearance**
[image]

Check **Enable Workspaces** and **Add show desktop icon to the launcher**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Left/Right combination works fine (and I have to admit I didn't know that). However, my original question is about dragging  the window using the mouse. Resetting Compiz does nothing. The last link you included is about the solutions I already mentioned in my original post. Thanks though

Comment: @xtian777x. Okay, I can also move the window by mouse | update the answer

Comment: Oh I see you are using Gnome. I forgot to mention I'm using Unity so I can't do what you show in your pic. I'll update my post.

Comment: @xtian777x the answer was updated

Comment: Oh I see where our misunderstanding lies. What you are doing, i.e. showing all workspaces and, from that view, drag a window to another workspace has always worked for me indeed. However, what I mean is dragging a window without using the Workspace Switcher view. On 14.04 I just drag the window to the screen's edge and the workspace moves along with the window. That's something I can't do on 16.04